# How do you say 直播 In English?

Tags: word

As eveyone knows that 直播 is Live.
But in this sentence:
What are you doing tonight?
看直播.(Watch Live)

I think it's a little strange.

PS:I watch online live, such as douyu.

Comment: 直播 direct broadcast, 看直播 watch direct (a/the live) broadcast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is also called **[live broadcast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_broadcast)** in English?

So depending on the context you would translate it to *live* or *broadcast*, or *live broadcast* if you don't mind a little bit of redundancy.

And [Marko](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/users/19368/marko) also made a good point about 网络直播, which is often called *stream* or *[live streaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_streaming)* in English. Douyu or Twitch would belong to this category.

Answer (score 2):

Most often, we use the term "stream" -- as in "I am going to watch Sccc's stream playing Dota 2 online" -> "我要看Sccc在网上的Dota 2 直播"

Broadcast is a more formal term used when the contents are broadcast onto a television or radio.

Answer (score 0):

直播 is short for 直接轉播 (direct relay / broadcast)

Saying '看直播' (**watching live**) is perfectly fine. '看直接轉播' is actually too wordy and strange sounding.

If you want to emphasize the 'live' aspect, you can say '看現場直播' (watching live on the scene) or '看即場直播'